# Mysql : Insert missing rows in a table based on another column value in same table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert new rows into a table where a value is missing based on the value in another column. So for example in the following table I want add a new row with value 2 for each ref where it is missing.

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | value | ref |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  |  1    |  1  |
| 2  |  2    |  1  |
| 3  |  7    |  1  |
| 4  |  1    |  2  |
| 5  |  7    |  2  |
| 6  |  1    |  3  |
| 7  |  7    |  3  |
| 8  |  8    |  3  |
+----+-------+-----+
```

So in the above I would get the additional 2 rows

```
+----+-------+-----+
| 9  |  2    |  2  |
| 10 |  2    |  3  |
+----+-------+-----+
```

This is probably quite basic, but so is my SQL.

Any help appreciated.

Just to clarify the question,

in the example I am adding the value 2 for all refs which don't have it. So those would be the additional rows, as ref 1 already has value 2. If for example I wanted to add the value 5 for all refs, this would add 3 new rows.

Comment: What is the logic behind the additional rows?

Comment: Are you using only Mysql?

Comment: @DevanshuGoyal yes only mysql

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure what you mean by the logic behind the additional rows,  but table is used to define which values are available for a given ref.  Adding the new rows increases the availability of a given value,

Comment: `+----+-------+-----+
| 9  |  2    |  2  |
| 10 |  2    |  3  |
+----+-------+-----+ ` why are you using 2,2 for 9 and 2,3 for 10 ? any logic for that ?

Comment: @JagaSrik just an exmple.  I am adding the value 2 for all refs which dont have it. So those would be the additional rows, as ref 1 already has value 2.  If for example I wanted to add the value 5 for all refs, this would add 3 new rows.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, please do update your question with this details in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work. Thought could do it using just the one table.  Turns out ref is a primary key in another table, so this seems to do it.

```
INSERT INTO ValeRefTable(value , ref)
SELECT 2, RT.id 
   FROM RefTable RT 
   WHERE RT.id NOT IN 
      (
          SELECT VRT.ref FROM ValueRefTable VRT WHERE VRT.value = 2
      )
```